# Where does SQL Server store deployed CLR Assemblies?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I have created a SQL CLR User defined function and deployed it to a database on a SQL Server instance, where it is working correctly.

Where does SQL Server store deployed CLR assemblies? Are they stored somewhere in the file system?

Comment: Clicking on Deploy where?

Answer (score 6):

Deployed User CLR assemblies are stored in the database you deploy them to, not on the file system.

Execute

```
SELECT * FROM sys.assembly_files
```

the column called `content` contains binary data *is* the assembly.

See [`CREATE ASSEMBLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx):

> Creates a managed application module that contains class metadata and
>   managed code as an object in an instance of SQL Server. By referencing
>   this module, common language runtime (CLR) functions, stored
>   procedures, triggers, user-defined aggregates, and user-defined types
>   can be created in the database

Comment: Upvoted. How good is it for performance? We have a lot of functions in C# which we required both in SQL and C# since they basically do the same work.

Comment: Also how can i prevent `pdb` files from getting deployed.

Comment: create the release version of the code. "How good is it for performance? " -  without context that is meaningless. TSQL string handling can be slow; I tend to perform this in  CLR procs.

Comment: @ExpertNovice If you are using Visual Studio / SSDT, you can prevent the deployment of the `.pdb` files by unchecking the "Include Symbols" option on the SQLCLR tab of Project Properties.

Comment: @ExpertNovice and Mitch: it might help to clarify in this answer that the Assembly itself will always be `file_id = 1` in `sys.assembly_files`. Other files, such as .pdb files, etc (if there are any), will be `file_id` > 1. Also, is there any reason to not accept this answer? It is correct, even more so if the clarification of `file_id = 1` is added :-).